# Xamarin: Can i mute my app while playing a video that the music in the background does not get stopped?

Tags: android, ios, audio, xamarin.forms

In the last weeks before migrating our xamarin-app to MAUI our customer came up with an very "important" improvement.. Currently when we are playing a video in our app, the background music playing from spotify, youtube music, etc. stops. This behaviour makes totally sense if our video would have an audio track. But it hasn´t. So they want us to change the code to still play music while watching the video (if the video has no audio track).

I read about the SetAudioFocusRequest for Android but this is not exactly what we need. Maybe there is a way to set the audio focus for our app regularly into background (or whatever it is called) and just set the audio focus when we have an audio track.

FYI we are playing videos via two ways. Either its an help/instruction video (contains audio) or an animated video (has no audio). These are separated and get called in different locations. So we know exactly, if the video has an audio track or not (or in other words if we have to mute the app or not).

Unfortunately I have not found anything helpful until yet. Maybe some of you guys has faced this issue and can help us.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service to stream audio to play audio while your application is not visible or under the lock screen.

You could check the blog about this here: [Background Audio Streaming with Xamarin.Android](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/background-audio-streaming-with-xamarin-android/) and download the sample from [Github](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/AndroidStreamingAudio/tree/master/Part%201%20-%20Simple%20Streaming).

Comment: this is not what i want to achive. I need it in the exact opposite way. I want to play a video in my app (this video has no audio). And because of the fact that i know that this video has no audio, i dont want to stop my music playing via Spotify or Youtube Music or any other music streaming app..

Comment: You can try to do this with [Manage audio focus](https://developer.android.com/media/optimize/audio-focus#java).